# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No enabled protocols

Tags: android, ssl, https, angular2-nativescript

I have this problem when I'm calling http post from my nativscript app to my Node server. I can't figure out what this error message means. I'm running the app on my Android KitKat device (API 19).

```
System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No enabled protocols; SSLv3 is no longer supported and was filtered from the list
System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.initialize(:com.google.android.gms@12521003@12.5.21 (000306-189987672):7)
System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@12521003@12.5.21 (000306-189987672):6)
System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.KitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@12521003@12.5.21 (000306-189987672))
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:543)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$1.run(Async.java:482)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(Async.java:52)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here's what I tried in my main.ts so far: (Edit2)

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";

import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

import { android as androidApp, AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBundleEventData } from "application";
import { ad } from "utils/utils";

declare let com: any;

if (androidApp) {
    const context = ad.getApplicationContext();

    androidApp.on(AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, function (args: AndroidActivityBundleEventData) {
        let builder = new android.os.StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        android.os.StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());                

        // Needed for corner cases with HTTP request using TSL on Android API19
        com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(
            context,
            new com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener({
                onProviderInstalled: () => {
                    console.log("Provider Installed!");
                    const sslContext = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
                    const engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                },
                onProviderInstallFailed: (errorCode, intent) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorCode);
                }
            }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error indicate that you need to enable SSLv3 protocol for communication.

Go to your jdk/jre/lib/security/java.security & remove SSLv3 protocol from **jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms** this list.

Then restart application !!!

Comment: I disagree. It only says that the protocol list is empty. KitKat supports at least TLSv1.0 therefore there should be no need to enable SSLv3. Furthermore your answer only applies to JRE/JDK on a PC, not to Android.

Comment: Hi @Abhijeet, may I know how to navigate to the folder? I can't seem to find it. Thanks.